# Can your companions die?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I've heard of some companions not leveling with the Courier, and being killed as a result. But every time my companions are beaten senseless, they end up merely unconscious.

Can companions die? If so, under what circumstances? Is this a "hardcore mode" thing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it's a hardcore feature, your companions CAN die to the enemies. There are various other ways [that companions can die](http://www.falloutwiki.com/Fallout:_New_Vegas_companions#Notes). They can be killed while they are not your companions. So, before getting them, or after dismissing them.

There are also some [reports](http://www.falloutwiki.com/Talk:Fallout:_New_Vegas_companions#unkillable) that companions can be killed in casual mode by doing massive damage to their bodies when they are knocked down. This is probably a bug.

Comment: So this is hardcore-only, I take it? But apparently I can kill my own companions if I gun them down (according to MariusRawr's answer)? (Not that I *would* ... in my first play-through, anyway. I only do the indiscriminate butcher thing in my last play-through ... :)

Comment: Yes hardcore only

Comment: So if they die in HC & then you switch to casual, do they come back or are they dead dead?

Answer (score 1):

I know they can die in both hardcore and casual. Hardcore being from anything and casual being from massive damage which only the courier can deal that much in such little time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they die on Hardcore, and I don't know whether it's possible to bring them back or whether you just have to replace them.

Answer (score -3):

Your companions can die, but not of enemies. If the Courier attacks his companion, he will die.

Comment: That's incorrect, your companions CAN die.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, they can die, but only by your hands.